# Why can I invoke a fun without passing parameter name in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There are 4 parameters with default value in function joinToString, in my mind, I should pass parameter value by order when I omit parameter name.

So I think the Code  `println(letters.joinToString( transform={ it.toLowerCase() } ) )` is right.

But in fact the Code `println(letters.joinToString { it.toLowerCase() } )`   is right too, why?

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.joinToString(
        separator: String = ", ",
        prefix: String = "",
        postfix: String = "",
        transform: (T) -> String = { it.toString() }
): String {
    val result = StringBuilder(prefix)

    for ((index, element) in this.withIndex()) {
        if (index > 0) result.append(separator)
        result.append(transform(element))
    }

    result.append(postfix)
    return result.toString()
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {  
    val letters = listOf("Alpha", "Beta")

    println(letters.joinToString { it.toLowerCase() } )               //It's Ok    
    println(letters.joinToString( transform={ it.toLowerCase() } ) )  //It's OK

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you're using a different syntax.

If the last param of a method is a method reference then you can omit the parenthesis and just pass in the function with the { brackets.

`it` in this case becomes `T` that you were passing into the function

```
println(letters.joinToString { it.toLowerCase() } )
```

Below is what you thought you were entering. This wouldn't compile and would require the named argument or for the params to be in the right order. You would also have to change the syntax from using `it` to using the regular functional syntax

```
println(letters.joinToString(it.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: I think the last line should be `println(letters.joinToString({ it.toLowerCase() }))`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dan's answer, you don't need to provide a named argument, but if you do so then you're forced to use the named argument for all the following arguments (from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments): "all the positional arguments should be placed before the first named one"). In your case the only named argument you're providing is the last one, and all other arguments have default values so you're not forced to provide them, as long as the default value is fine for you.